# Git ignore ANY changes to a git repository

Tags: git

**Problem:**

The way to do it on a per file basis is as follows:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

But for performance reasons as soon as I initialize a git repository I want to ignore any changes to any file that will be added to the repo.

**Solution:**

A solution for this is to put a `*` on a `.gitignore` file within the repo, and then we get the desired behaviour.

Is there a cleaner way? I.e. is there a git config command that will do the same as above?

Comment: Git is a version control system used primarily to track _changes_ to files. Do you really want to force it _not_ to track _changes_ to files? I think you should use another tool.

Comment: Why not simply extract a snapshot of the contents of the index and forget that it is a git repository then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a repository-local gitignore which is local to your clone of the repository, and is not stored as a `.gitignore` committed into the source tree itself, you can edit the file `yourrepo/.git/info/exclude`.

In here you could add a line containing `*` to achieve the same thing you would with a regular `.gitignore` file.